# NTFS external hard drive fixing

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I have a 1tb external hard drive which I partitioned into four parts but only the first two can open the rest they don't and a crc error is displayed when attempting to open. The disk have been using it with Windows but chckdisk has not fixed it. How can I fix that with ubuntu? I just need the drive okay whatever I is in there worries me not coz I have a back up .

Comment: I have the back up already .

Comment: Sorry misread it :) Try GParted, unmount the partitions and use then run a disk check on each of them (saving the output may also be useful). What filesystem is in use on the drives?

Comment: To be frank am a guy who uses windows I just started using ubuntu for Python programming . so I use NTFS file system .

Comment: Windows problems should be fixed with Windows tool. "How can I fix that with ubuntu?" You do not.

Comment: Hmmm on superuser [here](http://superuser.com/questions/298729/how-to-fix-a-damaged-corrupted-ntfs-filesystem-partition-without-losing-the-data) is says use a Ubuntu live cd, lol  - you can use [testdisk](http://superuser.com/questions/128821/fix-ntfs-partition) though.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, there are no Linux NTFS repair utilities. The `ntfsfix` tool might seem to be one, but it does only the most rudimentary checks and then flags the partition for repair in Windows. Thus, your best bet is to do the repair under Windows, and to ask about it on a Windows forum.

If you use a disk exclusively in Linux, NTFS is a poor choice. Part of the reason is what I've just related; but NTFS is also slow (in Linux) and lacks Unix/Linux filesystem features. For exchanging data between Windows and Linux, FAT is likely to be better, with the major caveat that FAT has a 4GiB file-size limit, which can be a show-stopping problem for many purposes, making NTFS a necessary choice for many people.

Comment: agreed - windowz can also use [ext2fs](http://www.ext2fsd.com/) to access ext2fs. exFAT is also a option (allows files larger than 4Gb), but it still needs windows to fix it etc as it proprietary.

Comment: For me to run the ntfsfix I have to install ntfsprogs and ntfs-3g, isn't that the case?

Comment: What's the ntfsprogs and ntfs-3g because have read that I should install them.... This now needs to get sleeve folded

Comment: My point is that `ntfsfix` is essentially worthless. At best, it will force Windows to check the disk.